# how to authenticate a link using requests

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use beautiful soup to extract data from a link...currently its failing authentication like below..how do I authenticate the link,I know the server that should be logged-in..where to provide the server path and how to validate the link?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import argparse
import urllib
import urllib2
import getpass
import re
import requests

def update (url):
    print url
    r = requests.get(url)
    html = r.text
    soup = bs(html)
def main ():
    #For logging
    print "test"
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='This is the update.py script created by test')
    parser.add_argument('-u','--url',action='store',dest='url',default=None,help='<Required> url link',required=True)
    results = parser.parse_args()# collect cmd line args
    url = results.url
    #print url
    update(url)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "announce_update2.py", line 24, in <module>
    main()
  File "announce_update2.py", line 22, in main
    update(url)
  File "announce_update2.py", line 11, in update
    r = requests.get(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-1.1.0-py2.7.egg\requests\api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-1.1.0-py2.7.egg\requests\api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-1.1.0-py2.7.egg\requests\sessions.py", line 289, in request
    history = [r for r in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-1.1.0-py2.7.egg\requests\sessions.py", line 133, in resolve_redirects
    proxies=proxies
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-1.1.0-py2.7.egg\requests\sessions.py", line 279, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, stream=stream, timeout=timeout, verify=verify, cert=cert, proxies=proxies)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-1.1.0-py2.7.egg\requests\sessions.py", line 374, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-1.1.0-py2.7.egg\requests\adapters.py", line 213, in send
    raise SSLError(e)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Comment: Is the url internal or public? If it's public could you share it, if it's internal, is the certificate signed by a internal CA, which isn't present in requests builtin list of CAs?

Comment: @t-8ch - its an internal link...it needs to be authenticated on a server login.company.com....how to do that?

Comment: If it needs to be authenticated, you need a signed certificate, either by yourself & trust it, or buy one from the companies already trusted by default. If it doesn't, just don't verify it...

Comment: You internal CAs certificate should be bundled with your internal browser. You can extract the cert from this browsers certificate manager. Most browsers allow you to click the "lock"-symbol next to your URL bar to show the chain of trust of your current page. Somewhere in this window should be a button to export the certificate to a file (export the CAs certificate, not the servers, use bas64 encoding). Then pass the filename of the exported cert to requests with the `verify` parameter.

Comment: If you use [this package](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification), just pass `verify=False`.

Comment: @user2125827 If you pass [`verify=False`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification) to `requests.get()` it skips verification. But you *really* shouldn't do this. Internal certificates are absolutely fine and there is a reason people are using them.

Comment: @t-8ch - you are right..i get the error <h1>401: Access Denied</h1> if i do verify flase..it still not clear on how can I validte..